# akka.persistence.typed.internal.JournalFailureException: Exception during recovery. How to solve it?

Tags: java, jackson, akka, akka-persistence

Using Akka persistence I get this exception:

> Caused by: akka.persistence.typed.internal.JournalFailureException:
>   Exception during recovery. Last known sequence number [0].
>   PersistenceId [PersistenceExample], due to: Cannot construct instance
>   of `com.exercisePersistence.simpleExample.MyPersistentBehavior$Added`
>   (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object
>   value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)  at [Source:
>   (byte[])"{"data":"data1"}"; line: 1, column: 2]   at
>   akka.persistence.typed.internal.ReplayingEvents.onRecoveryFailure(ReplayingEvents.scala:221)
>     at
>   akka.persistence.typed.internal.ReplayingEvents.onJournalResponse(ReplayingEvents.scala:143)
>     ... 26 common frames omitted
>
> Caused by:
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot
>   construct instance of
>   `com.exercisePersistence.simpleExample.MyPersistentBehavior$Added`
>   (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object
>   value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)  at [Source:
>   (byte[])"{"data":"data1"}"; line: 1, column: 2]

The class Added that give me exception is:

```
public class MyPersistentBehavior 
    extends EventSourcedBehavior<MyPersistentBehavior.Command, 
        MyPersistentBehavior.Event, MyPersistentBehavior.State> {

    // COMMAND
    interface Command {}
    public static class Add implements Command {
      public final String data;

      public Add(String data) {
        this.data = data;
      }
    }
...
}
```

File reference.conf

```
akka {
 actor {
serializers {
  jackson-json = "akka.serialization.jackson.JacksonJsonSerializer"
  jackson-cbor = "akka.serialization.jackson.JacksonCborSerializer"
  proto = "akka.remote.serialization.ProtobufSerializer"
}
serialization-bindings {
  "com.exercisePersistence.simpleExample.MyPersistentBehavior" = jackson-json
  "com.exercisePersistence.simpleExample.MyPersistentBehavior$Added" = jackson-json
  #"docs.serialization.CborSerializable" = jackson-cbor
  "com.google.protobuf.Message" = proto
}
```

}

```
akka.serialization.jackson {
      jackson-json-message {
        serialization-features {
          WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS = on
        }
      }
      jackson-json-event {
        serialization-features {
          WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS = off
        }
      }
  }
  persistence {
    journal {
      plugin = "leveldb"

      leveldb {
        dir = "target/persistence/journal"
      }
    }

    snapshot-store.local.dir = "target/persistence/snapshots"
  }
}

leveldb {
  dir = "target/persistence/journal"
  checksum: "off"
  class: "akka.persistence.journal.leveldb.LeveldbJournal"
  dir: "target/persistence/journal"
  fsync: "on"
  native: "on"
  plugin-dispatcher : "akka.persistence.dispatchers.default-plugin-dispatcher"
  replay-dispatcher : "akka.persistence.dispatchers.default-replay-dispatcher"
}
```

If want to clone the project this is the Github link: https://github.com/Mazzotta13/AkkaTutorial.git

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple different options:

1. Since you're serializing with Jackson you can add `@JsonCreator` annotation to your constructor in protocol objects.
2. You can use Lombak to create your protocol objects which saves on a lot of java boiler plate and annotate it with `@NoArgsConstructor`.
3. Create an empty constructor.

Some information on it can be found here, https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/serialization-jackson.html#annotations